# Both READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON and ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking, snapshot-isolation

I inherited a SQL Server 2012 instance that hosts Hyperion databases. I believe the Hyperion techs configured the system and they have both `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON` and `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON` at the same time. This doesn't make sense to me. Does it make sense?

Also I am seeing 60-70% of the waits are `Lock_M_X`, which is much higher than i have ever seen. Wondering if this might be related to the above.

And I have been running 1 minute `sp_whoisactive` snapshots into a table and have not been able to capture a single X type lock. A reasonable number of S type locks show up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

From a previous answer to this:

> If you use `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` make sure you use `SET
>   TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT` in your code, otherwise you will
>   not get any of the benefits.
>
> If you set `SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON`, then there is no need to
>   modify any code. MS SQL Server automatically applies snapshot
>   isolation for that table.

Basically, with only `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLAION`, you still have to specify the isolation level in the query/SP to make it use that isolation level.

With `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` set to ON, the DB is automatically in that mode and there's no need to modify your queries.

[ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION and READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40738/allow-snapshot-isolation-and-read-committed-snapshot)

In the answer I linked to above, there is a link to Kim Tripp's video on snapshot isolation.  It's pure gold.